# What does the expression "BIO *client = (BIO *)arg" mean?

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

Here is the context of the code:

```
void THREAD_CC server_thread(void *arg)
{
    BIO *client = (BIO *)arg;
        ...
}
```

Does the expression `(BIO *)arg` transform the void pointer `arg` into a pointer that points to BIO? I'm not sure if I got this right or not.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Z.Zen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called a cast; it doesn't transform the pointer, it persuades the compiler to take your word that the incoming pointer (which is untyped) is actually a pointer to BIO, and to treat it as such.

Comment: Yes. That's the only right answer possible. Such cast doesn't "transform" anything, it just asks the compiler to shut up.

Comment: No, it *does* transform the pointer.  If a `void *` pointer and a `BIO *` pointer have different representations, it'll change the former into the latter.  It's equivalent to casting `int` to `long` - sure, on *some* systems it might be a no-op, but not in general.

Comment: @caf ?? what do you mean? that the "nature" of a pointer can change according to the pointee?

Comment: @ShinTakezou: Exactly - the size, representation and alignment requirements of *pointer-to-type-A* can differ from that of *pointer-to-type-B*.  There are some limitations on this - eg. `void *` and `char *` must be the same, all pointers to `struct` must be the same.  This allows, for example, the implementation to tag pointer types with type information that is checked at dereference time.

Comment: @caf still I can't understand the point, likely it's my limit. To me, `type *p` is just a way to say that p is a pointer (and this, qualifies it exactly, given a certain machine); to what, it is interesting only to the C language to be able to know which instruction must be produced by `*p = x`, or `p++`, or `p->field`; but the pointer is not changed at all, just the metainfo about it that are needed by the compiler; for `int` e `long` instead, the argument is different, since if they don't match in size, the datum can be really altered

Comment: ShinTakezou: Although that's how most common machines work today (all pointers look the same underneath), it's not in general required by the C standard (and if the authors of the standard had wanted to make that guarantee, they would have).  For example, a machine where `double` must be 8 byte aligned might plausibly use the *lower* `N-3` bits of the pointer value to address `double` s in memory - on such a machine, converting `double *` to and from `void *` would require a shift.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `(BIO *)` **casts** the `void *` pointer (arg) to be of type `BIO *`

Answer (score 1):

It transforms (casts) the void* into a pointer of type BIO*. It does not "point to" BIO.

Answer (score 0):

Your input variable `arg` is of type void. [Typecasting](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson11.html) just casts the variable of one type to another. This is useful when you pass pointers as arguments to different functions and typecast them to their original type when dereferencing them.

In the above case your typecasting `arg` from (void *) type to (BIO *) type. Now you can access the members of the ponter `client` like you would do to a normal BIO * pointer type.